# Is imageview needed within this imageview?

Tags: android, imageview

[image: The image is a mountain and sun]

I use an `ImageView` to display the entire image. I want to launch the next activity when the sun is touched. Is it possible by using this single image or should i use separate imageview for sun? I know how to do it with separate imageview. I want to know whether it is possible by using only the full image?

Comment: Better if you do it with two image views. With one `ImageView` you will have to handle the touch event, then lookup the `Event.x,y` to see if it is on top of the _"sun"_ (use geometry to find if `x,y` falls inside the circumference of circle) and then execute your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two imageviews

Easier and less bug-prone